# c++ get stream modifier from << overload

Tags: c++, stream, overloading

I have overloaded the stream insertion operator like this :

```
template<class Ch, class Tr, class word_type>
std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>&
operator << (std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& s, const Mabit::mabit<word_type>& obj)
{
  s << obj.to_string(Mabit::DEC, ',');
  return s;
}
```

(mabit being the class for which i wanted the overload to work)

That is, since i can give different argument to the `to_string` method, i would like to be able to use standard stream modifier like `std::dec`, `std::hex` ... in a way that i could retrieve them from the overloaded operator to prepare the good argument as parameter for `to_string`

If i could also get the locale being used (to extract the separator for thousands) , it would be helpfull for the second argument too...

Is that possible ?

Comment: See if this one works for you:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/numpunct/thousands_sep/

Comment: Thanks AlexK, it was the last missing part after the answer of Steven Maitlall !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::basic_ostream::flags()` to identify whether an format specifier was used.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags

Answer (score 1):

From  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/numpunct/thousands_sep/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int q=10977;
  char separator = use_facet<numpunct<char> >(cout.getloc()).thousands_sep ();
  cout << q/1000 << separator << q%1000 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I suppose you can just replace cout with your stream argument in this example